# Moving reports from Personal folder of particular user to another folder

Tags: custom-reports

I have a requirement in which we need to move some reports of particular user's personal folder to another folder in salesforce. So tell me the bulkified way to  move.Your response will be highly appricated

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling led me to this:

[How do I mass-move reports into one new folder?"](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7fnASAR)

The steps highlighted by Matt Brown are:

- Create a new project
- Include ‘reports’ or more specifically the report folders you are concerned with
- Let Eclipse refresh the project with the reports metadata
- In Eclipse, navigate to the reports folder you just download and then select the Report Folder you want the reports you want to move from, right click and select Properties
- Take Note of the Location. This is the path where the metadata files are located
- Open a windows explorer window and navigate to that path
- Highlight all the Reports you want to move and right click Cut
- Still in the Window explorer navigate back to the list of report folder and expand the one you want to move the reports to and right click and Paste
- Now back in the IDE highlight the folder titled Reports and right click and Refresh and then right click again and Force.com>Save to Server
- BOOM! Now you have moved your reports.

I haven't tried this myself so I would definately recommend doing it a Sandbox Org first. I also found this article that may be of use of you get stuck [Updating Reports with Eclipse and the Force.Com IDE](https://teachmesalesforce.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/updating-reports-with-eclipse-and-the-force-com-ide/).

One suggested method that requires a bit of work and is a manual process via the Salesforce UI is discussed here:
[How do you move multiple Reports from one folder to another at the same time?](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7LnOSAV)

And finally, an idea you can up-vote as this functionality could be useful:
[Mass moving reports between folders](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdo9yUAB/mass-moving-reports-between-folders)